# defining merge policy parameters for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

According to http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/merge/
I can control the merge policy and the parameters of the merge policy.

I am unclear on how to do that.
When creating the index, if I want to limit the size of a segment, can I do:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://ec2-23-22-207-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9200/my_index/' -d '{
    "settings" : {"index":{
        "number_of_shards" : 10,
        "number_of_replicas" : 2,
    "merge":{"policy":{"max_merged_segmentss" : "2gb"}}}
    }
}'
```

This seems to work. Such that:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/_settings?pretty=true'
```

yields:

```
{
  "my_index" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index.number_of_replicas" : "2",
      "index.number_of_shards" : "10",
      "index.merge.policy.max_merged_segment" : "2gb",
      "index.version.created" : "900199"
    }
  }
}
```

However, If i instead change `max_merged_segment` with some random flag `some_random` it will just yield:

```
{
  "my_index" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index.number_of_replicas" : "2",
      "index.number_of_shards" : "10",
      "index.merge.policy.some_random" : "2gb",
      "index.version.created" : "900199"
    }
  }
}
```

which leads me to suspect I am doing something wrong.

Also, how would I change the actual merge policy, say from `tiered` to `log_byte_size`? Can I do this at runtime, or only at index creation?

Answer (score 0):

As of Elasticsearch 2.0, none of these settings are configurable anymore (although this is surely not the problem you were having at the time as that was well before 2.0)
* https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/breaking_20_setting_changes.html#_merge_and_merge_throttling_settings
* https://discuss.elastic.co/t/tiered-merge-policy-settings-not-documented-in-2-x-gone/61470/2